# Avoiding memory allocations with linear algebra calculations in R

Tags: r, memory, linear-algebra

As a trivial case, let's say I'm interested in calculating:

```
r = v*M^t
```

Where r and v are vectors and M is an extremely large sparse matrix.

I can solve it one of two ways:

```
r = v*(M*M*M*M...)
r = ((((v*M)M)M)M)...
```

Where the first approach results in intermediate dense matrices that is impractical to store in RAM (I would need at least 10's of terabytes for my target minimum use case). The second solution , instead, always results in intermediate vectors, and it does in fact work in practice.

The problem is that at larger values of *t*, memory allocations are causing a substantial performance bottleneck.

```r
library(pryr)

n = 20000

v = 1:n

M = matrix(1:(n*n), n) # Not a sparse matrix like my use case, but easier to start with

for (i in 1:10) {
  v = v %*% M
  print(address(v))
}
```

As the address() function shows, *v* is being reallocated every iteration. It is not being modified in place. Not only are the memory allocations slowing things down, but according to profvis, the garbage collector is constantly being called as well and taking up a large portion of the time.

So my question is, is there a way to perform this calculation (and potentially others similar to it) in R without the excess memory allocations and gc() calls happening under the hood?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I'm aware. I actually have several equations I'm implementing, many of which aren't even computationally feasible in their native form. I'm at the point where I've optimized most of them to be feasible using various tricks, but as I get to that point, memory allocations and the garbage collector in general are becoming increasingly more of the performance bottleneck for some of them. I'm hoping an answer to this more trivial example will be applicable to them

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Thanks, I had forgotten about data.table and it's an interesting thought given the adavantages it has. Unfortunately, having the question written down and thinking about it more, I realized that the `%*%` operator/function is probably allocating a vector internally and returning a reference, in which case there probably isn't anything I can do without writing or finding a specialized function (likely in c++) to manage the calculation and memory the way I need it. Maybe someone can verify this as an answer